# WSL - "wsl --set-version <Distr Name> 2" does not work

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I tried to set my kali-linux to WSL2 but, even after "wsl --set-version kali-linux 2" the Version won't change =(

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9zV7.png

I also tried to change kali-linux to default wsl and try to use "wsl --set-default-version 2", but that also didn't affect the output

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYUsF.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oa6Zn.png

Comment: You have to activate Windows-Hypervisor-Plattform and restart your computer